# Is it safe to remove dependencies in the controller function when the directive does not seem to use them?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The following controller does not seem to use $element, $attrs, $transclude. The controller code below runs fine if these params are commented out.

```
myApp.directive("menu", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: "<div class='menu' data-ng-transclude></div>",
        controller: function ($scope ,$element, $attrs, $transclude) {
            $scope.submenus = [];
            console.log('[$element]->', $element);
            console.log('[$attrs]->', $attrs);
            console.log('[$transclude]->', $transclude);
            this.addSubmenu = function (submenu) {
                console.log('[addToggleMenu]->');
               $scope.submenus.push(submenu);
            }

            this.closeAllOtherPanes = function (displayedPane) {
                angular.forEach($scope.submenus, function (submenu) {
                    if (submenu != displayedPane) {
                        console.log('[displayedPane]->', displayedPane);
                        submenu.removeDisplayClass();
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is [my working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gogirl/CCe3x/2/).

Since posting, I have learned that in JavaScript, a function can be called with any number  of arguments no matter how many of them are listed. In some languages, a programmer may write two functions with same name but different parameter list, and the interpreter/compiler would choose the right one. That is called function polymorphism. Having used function polymorphism most of my career I expected to be told "Hey , you're not using this param". Also I did not understand that well that the controller parameters are dependencies while the link function parameters are order based. I still struggle in understanding whether $scope, $element or commonly used parameters in the directives internal controller are required and which are optional. Apparently the $ is only required in the controller and not in link because of the DI injection of angular services..whew lot to digest.

A special thanks to Esteban for explaining special pseudo-array inside each function 
called arguments. This explains the link function which is half the equation. So I have rewritten the question in hopes that it may get answered.  [This excellent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238191/understanding-angular-js-controller-parameters),
straightened out most of my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you wanting to remove the $attrs argument? The directive's arguments are in a specific order and removing any one of them will cause subsequent arguments to not be what you think they are.

Say you changed your link function to something like this:

```
function ($scope, $iElement, menuController) {
        menuController.addSubmenu($scope); // this will throw  an exception 
                                           // because menuController is actually
                                           // $attrs
```

The reason for this is due to the fact that the function will be called with the same arguments passed in regardless of whether they were defined in your directive's link function.

```
function argTest(one, two){
    console.log('argTest.arguments', arguments);
    // even though I don't have three defined, it is still passed in:
    console.log('three is passed in', arguments[2]);
}
argTest(1,2,3);
```

JSFiddle for above: http://jsfiddle.net/TwoToneBytes/NM8DK/

Comment: Esteban I take them out as I wrote because I am trying to figure out how the iAttr is used within the link function. You say its the menu controller. I thought it was caption in the scope. How can I verify that I was wrong?(ex in Batarang). The controller code above runs fine even if $element, $attrs, $transclude are commented out. How can I verify that they are needed or not?

Comment: I just did a console.log and $iAttr and menuController are quite different beasts. $iAttr points to each clickable object that has a caption while the controller is the api supplier. I want to remove unused params ($element, $attrs, $transclude)from the menu controller. How do I know when it is safe to do that?

Comment: On the other hand, when removing IAttr I can see that the exception is indeed raised on the menu controller object so am I to believe the console.log or the exception? Hope someone can shed some light.

Comment: I am still questioning why you want to remove arguments? What are you trying to do? Just removing arguments won't change what's passed into the arguments.

Comment: Esteban I am trying to understand the responsibility of that which is being injected into the code. I assume that it is there for a reason. By removing it, I decompose the directive into smaller parts that I can understand. If for example, $transclude does nothing at all, I don't want to include it in my code. I find it hard to unit test or mock what I dont understand.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Okay, well the directive link function has a specific function definition which is function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude). Even if you remove all of the arguments, it will still be passed in. There is no need to remove those arguments from the function definition, you can see what I mean here: http://jsfiddle.net/TwoToneBytes/CCe3x/3/

Comment: Did not see this till now. Was hidden. Esteban, can you pls see my cleaned up new version of the question. My javascript illiteracy keeps tripping me but I learn Angular much faster than js. Your answer definately taught me something but were I to write the code I would want to be sure that I do not leave out some vital dependency. It is getting clearer thx to everyone's help.