# Service failed to inject into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got this error

> Argument 'AppCtrl' is not a function, got string

my app.js as below :

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ionic']);

App.service("FreshlyPressed", ["$http","$log",FreshlyPressed]);
App.controller("AppCtrl", "FreshlyPressed", ["$scope", "$log", AppCtrl]);

function AppCtrl($scope, FreshlyPressed, $log){
  $scope.refresh = function(){
    FreshlyPressed.getBlogs(); 
  }
}

function FreshlyPressed($http, $log){
    this.getBlogs = function(){
        $http.jsonp("https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/freshly-pressed?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
        .success(function(result){
            $log.info(JSON.stringify(result.posts));
        });
    }
}
```

not sure where had I went wrong, I already FreshlyPressed as param into AppCtrl function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the line

**From**

```
App.controller("AppCtrl", "FreshlyPressed", ["$scope", "$log", AppCtrl]);
```

**To**

```
App.controller("AppCtrl", ["$scope", "$log", "FreshlyPressed", AppCtrl]);
```

And also the controller function should be like this

```
function AppCtrl($scope, $log, FreshlyPressed){
  $scope.refresh = function(){
    FreshlyPressed.getBlogs(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: oops I messed up there. But the order of param really matter in the controller function?

Comment: No but it should be easy to handle when using more parameters :)

Comment: Check out this with first answer it will be useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238191/understanding-angular-js-controller-parameters